# How to correctly order in a query that displays five rows and a row that summarizes the rest?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following MySQL query:

```
select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
    from (
             (
                 select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                     from queues order by queue_name limit 5 
             )
             union all
             (
                 select 'others' as queue_name ,
                        sum(jobs_pending) as jobs_pending,
                        sum(jobs_running) as jobs_running 
                     from (
                              select jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                                  from queues order by queue_name 
                                  limit 18446744073709551615 offset 5 
                     ) foo
             )
        ) foo;
```

In the above query the queue name filters the rows by limit 5.Then it sums the jobs_pending and job_running column from the offset 5 that it adds after the 5th row.

Now my query is i want to arrange the rows descendingly for both jobs_pending and jobs_running simultaneously and addition should be performed after descending the rows.The remaining rows after 5th row should be added and stored in the others row .How can i do it?

Another query which i had tried by adding desc:

```
select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
    from (
             (
                 select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                     from queues order by queue_name desc limit 5 
             )
             union all
             (
                 select 'others' as queue_name ,
                        sum(jobs_pending) as jobs_pending,
                        sum(jobs_running) as jobs_running 
                     from (
                              select jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                                  from queues order by queue_name desc
                                  limit 18446744073709551615 offset 5 
                     ) foo
             )
        ) foo;
```

But here the query desc happens with the queue_name column.I need that jobs_pending and jobs_running should be in descending to ascending level simultaneously .As per jobs_running and jobs_pending the queue_name name should be rearranged.

obtained output:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| queue_name   | jobs_pending | jobs_running |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| dsp_ncsim_hp |        11262 |           82 |
| adice_short  |         2865 |          274 |
| ncsim_long   |          741 |          116 |
| adice_ncsim  |          109 |          150 |
| normal       |          133 |           31 |
| others       |            5 |          184 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Expected:

Jobs_running need to be changed.Here jobs_running column is fetching as per jobs_pending column.Jobs_pending should be sorted from maximum to minimum level as per queue_name.Here jobs_running column is not arranged from maximum to minimum level.

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| queue_name   | jobs_pending | jobs_running |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| dsp_ncsim_hp |        11262 |           82 |
| adice_short  |         2865 |          274 |
| ncsim_long   |          741 |          116 |
| adice_ncsim  |          109 |          150 |
| normal       |          133 |           31 |
| others       |            5 |          184 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

In the above table running is not in this order.How can i sort jobs_running and jobs_pending independently by its value.

For jobs_running:-

```
  +-------------+--------------+--+
    | queue_name    | jobs_running |
    +--------------+---------------+
    |adice_short    |          274 |
    | adice_ncsim   |          150 |
    | ncsim_long    |          116 |
    | dsp_ncsim_hp  |          82  |
    | normal        |          31  |
    | others        |         184  |
    +--------------+---------------+
```

For jobs_pending:-

```
    +--------------+--------------+
    | queue_name   | jobs_pending |
    +--------------+--------------+
    | dsp_ncsim_hp |        11262 |
    | adice_short  |         2865 | 
    | ncsim_long   |          741 | 
    | adice_ncsim  |          109 |  
    | normal       |          133 |   
    | others       |            5 | 
    +--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: `limit 18446744073709551615` why is this here?  Also this is not a Perl question at all.

Comment: just i gave the maximum level of limit randomly.Because i dont know the how long the table will limits@dan1111

Comment: Then you don't need the limit clause, just remove it.

Comment: if i remove limit it shows error as follows.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'offset 5 ) foo)) foo'@JorgeCampos

Comment: @gore, ok, so you want to show five individual rows, and then you want to show a line that summarizes all other rows except those five.  I get that.  But what do you mean by "should be in descending to ascending level simultaneously"?  It's not clear.  Maybe you could provide some example data?

Comment: Yes you are right.descending to ascending level means.Jobs_pending and jobs_running should be arranged from maximum to minimum level.Highest value should be in first row and the lowest value should in fifth row.remaining values that is after five individual rows it should be added and stored in the others row.@dan1111

Comment: i had added my obtained output and expected output from your query@dan1111

Comment: From above query you are adding the job_pending and jobs_running columns together along with queue_name.Instead how to take queue_name,jobs_pending(max to min level) and queue_name,jobs_running (max to min level) and finally print it together.@dan1111

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, which orders by the total of both running and pending jobs:

```
select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
    from (
             (
                 select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                     from queues order by jobs_pending+jobs_running desc limit 5 
             )
             union all
             (
                 select 'others' as queue_name ,
                        sum(jobs_pending) as jobs_pending,
                        sum(jobs_running) as jobs_running 
                     from (
                              select jobs_pending,jobs_running 
                                  from queues order by jobs_pending+jobs_running desc
                                  limit 18446744073709551615 offset 5 
                     ) foo
             )
        ) foo;
```

Update: here is an alternative design that avoids the offset/limit.

```
with top_5_rows as (
    select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
        from queues order by jobs_pending+jobs_running desc limit 5 
)
select coalesce(top_5_rows.queue_name,'others'),
       sum(queues.jobs_tpending) as jobs_pending,
       sum(queues.jobs_running) as jobs_running
    from queues
    left outer join top_5_rows on
        top_5_rows.queue_name = queues.queue_name
    group by top_5_rows.queue_name
    order by case when top_5_rows.queue_name is not null then queuename else 'zzzzz' end
```

Comment: This is Okay.But since the values are shuffled not in and order.Is it possible to avoid giving limit value manually and considering the default limit value  and performing the same query@dan1111

Comment: The output is okay.Is it possible to use the limit without the number which i used .@dan1111

Comment: what is meant by coalesce@dan1111

Comment: @gore it returns the first non null element. In this case, the rows that aren't in the top 5 will be grouped under null for this column.

Comment: But i get the following error with the query which you have updated which as follows:ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'with top_5_rows as (
    select queue_name,jobs_pending,jobs_running 
        fr' at line 1@dan1111